# Phantom.js .NET authentication failure

Tags: phantomjs

Once I submit the form (either by `form.submit()` or `element.click()`), the page reloads but, is not redirected to the authenticated side of the site. It's simply the same page as the authentication failed page. The difference though is that, the new rendered page has the password removed from the password field.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onUrlChanged = function(url) {
console.log('Change to: ' + url);
};
page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
page.reason = resourceError.errorString;
page.reason_url = resourceError.url;
};

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/46.0.1 (X11; Linux x86_64)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36'
page.viewportSize = { width: 1280, height: 1024 };

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
console.log(msg);
};

page.open('https://www.some site/default.asp',function(status) {
console.log("Status: " + status);
if(status === "success") {

  page.evaluate(function() {

console.log("set values in a aform");

var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");

x[8].value="blaa";
x[9].value="blaa";
x[10].value="blaa";
x[11].click();
});



  window.setTimeout(function () {  

      phantom.exit();
    }, 9000);


  page.render('bsplogin1.png');

 }
else{

 console.log( "page not open!" );
        phantom.exit( 0 );
}});
```

Comment: thank you for editing . any solution please

Comment: You need to use the `--cookies-file` option: `./phantomjs --cookies-file=./my_file test.js >/dev/stdout`